# Can You Enable Bean Overriding On A Single Test Class?

Tags: java, spring-boot

One of my test classes has conflicts between the test beans and the production beans.

I can fix that by adding `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` to my test `application.properties`.

However, this now applies to all the tests.

Is it possible to apply this to a single test?
e.g. with an annotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can set properties in the *`SpringBootTest`* annotation.

```
@SpringBootTest(properties = 
{ "spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding = true" })
class TestClass{}
```